# Nginx routing all request to a location specified in config

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following section in `nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /main/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.10:3001/main/console/;

        auth_basic "Main Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Now if I hit `http://localhost:8080/main` it successfully displays the page that is running on `http://192.168.0.10:3001/main/console/`. However now even if I do `http://localhost:8080/main/blah/blah/blah` it redirects me to the same page as `http://192.168.0.10:3001/main/console/`

Due to this.. I have some static content being served in the page and the reference in the `HTML` is referred as `<script src='/main/resources/myapp/images/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'>`
This content is not displayed on the page as it's redirecting me back to the main page.

How do I resolve this issue?

EDIT:
 
What I want to achieve:
 
1. I want to proxy a few URI that I use in my application. For eg: I want to proxy `http://localhost:8080/main` to `http://192.168.0.10:3001/main/console/`
And `http://localhost:8080/register` to `http://192.168.0.10:3001/main/register/`
2. This application running in `http://192.168.0.10:3001` is started off from a `jar` file and it's using `jetty` server. So any images contained within the `jar` should be served normally through `proxy` as well 
 
3. I don't want `http://localhost:8080/main/blah/blah/blah` to still redirect to `http://192.168.0.10:3001/main/console/`. Only `http://localhost:8080/main` should redirect to `http://192.168.0.10:3001/main/console/`

Comment: Please describe, what  you want to achieve by your nginx configuration?

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler: I have updated my question with my intent

Comment: Why do you thint nginx would do what you think, not wrote it down  within nginx.conf? For example for exact mach you should use `location = /main {}` Your specs is not full, use cases are trivial, sorry don't have free time to continue.